# Fork loop installing Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM on OS X 10.7

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

When trying to use RVM to install Ruby 1.9.3 on my OS 10.7 MBP, I get an infinite loop as it tries to find another Ruby to do the install:

```
$ rvm system
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Warning! Requested ruby installation which requires another ruby available - installing one first.

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Warning! Requested ruby installation which requires another ruby available - installing one first.

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Warning! Requested ruby installation which requires another ruby available - installing one first.

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Warning! Requested ruby installation which requires another ruby available - installing one first.

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
^C
To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.


To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.


To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.


To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.
```

Of course, there IS a ruby present or we wouldn't have gotten that far:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

Any idea what might be causing this, and how to fix?

Comment: It does say “ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby”, which your Ruby (1.8.7) is not.

Comment: what version of rvm is that? this could be problem after failed head installation, check: `echo $rvm_head_flag`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem recently on OS X 10.8 with ruby-1.8.7. Upgrading rvm helped in my case. I've done:

```
$ rvm get stable
```

And then:

```
$ rvm use system
$ rvm install 1.8.7-p374
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before, but did you mean `rvm use system` instead of `rvm system`?

Try

```
$ rvm use system
```

to tell rvm to use the preinstalled ruby.

Then

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

Moreover, looking at the rvm install script, it looks like this only affects ruby 1.9 and ruby 2.0. If the above doesn't work, try installing ruby 1.8.7 through rvm first.